# Aligning text on the same line horizontally in HTML

Tags: html, alignment, text-align

I would like to create some text [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSw1n.png)

I used this code, but it didn't work:

```
woman <span style="padding-left:40px"> TextTextTextText</span> <br>
Man <span style="padding-left:40px"> TextTextTextText</span>
```

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```css
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}
.right {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="left">woman</span>
  <span class="right">TextTextTextText</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="left">Man</span>
  <span class="right">TextTextTextText</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a table:

```css
.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Woman</td>
                <td class="right">TextTextTextTop</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">Man</td>
                <td class="right">TextTextTextBottom</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want some more space between them, then you can add `padding-right: 40px;` to the `.left` declaration in the CSS:

```
.left {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

As [Prem Signh said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69206162/7364775), you can hide the border with `<table style="border: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">` instead of `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
    table {
        border: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .pl-40 {
        padding-left: 40px;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Woman</td>
            <td class="pl-40">TextTextTextText</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Man</td>
            <td class="pl-40">TextTextTextText</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```